# Passar texto no pl/sql para maiúscula

Tags: oracle, pl-sql

Tenho muitos scripts de create table, sequence e etc, porém tudo está em minúsculo, que o colega fez. Apagar linha a linha e colocar em maiúsculo é improdutivo, pois são mais de 1000 scripts para alterar. No SQL Server eu seleciono e dou **Ctrl+Shift+U** e passo o texto selecionado para maiúscula. Como eu faço isso no PL/SQL? Tenho pesquisado na NET e só vem passar os Dados(string) para maiúscula, tipo(`Upper(meu_campo)`) e não é isso que eu quero e sim alterar o script. Como eu faço?

Comment: Só consegui fazer assim. Copia o script e joga no Notepad++, dá um Crtl+Shift+U e depois copia e cola no PL/SQL. Meu colega disse que não tem como fazer isso no PL/SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tem como sim,

Via PL/SQL acessando o meno **Tools > Preferences**, no grupo **User Interface** existe a opção **PL/SQL Beautifier**.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Configurando o **Rules File**, clique em Edit..:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Assim automaticamente essa modificação que deseja é feita através da opção na barra de tarefas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
<sup>Também pode ser inserido um atalho, Tools > Preferences > no grupo User Interface existe a opção Key Configuration, e atribua um atalho ao comando.</sup>

Outra opção, você pode carregar um Roles File, como exemplo:
Copie o código abaixo e salve com a extensão `.br`

```
Version=1
RightMargin=90
Indent=3
UseTabCharacter=FALSE
TabCharacterSize=3
AlignDeclarationGroups=TRUE
AlignAssignmentGroups=TRUE
KeywordCase=1
IdentifierCase=0
UseSpecialCase=TRUE
ItemList.Format=2
ItemList.Align=TRUE
ItemList.CommaAfter=TRUE
ItemList.AtLeftMargin=FALSE
EmptyLines=2
ThenOnNewLine=FALSE
LoopOnNewLine=FALSE
DML.LeftAlignKeywords=FALSE
DML.LeftAlignItems=FALSE
DML.OnOneLineIfPossible=TRUE
DML.WhereSplitAndOr=TRUE
DML.WhereAndOrAfterExpression=FALSE
DML.WhereAndOrUnderWhere=TRUE
DML.InsertItemList.Format=2
DML.InsertItemList.Align=FALSE
DML.InsertItemList.CommaAfter=TRUE
DML.InsertItemList.AtLeftMargin=FALSE
DML.SelectItemList.Format=2
DML.SelectItemList.Align=TRUE
DML.SelectItemList.CommaAfter=TRUE
DML.SelectItemList.AtLeftMargin=FALSE
DML.UpdateItemList.Format=2
DML.UpdateItemList.Align=TRUE
DML.UpdateItemList.CommaAfter=TRUE
DML.UpdateItemList.AtLeftMargin=FALSE
ParameterDeclarationList.Format=2
ParameterDeclarationList.Align=TRUE
ParameterDeclarationList.CommaAfter=TRUE
ParameterDeclarationList.AtLeftMargin=FALSE
RecordFieldList.Format=1
RecordFieldList.Align=TRUE
RecordFieldList.CommaAfter=TRUE
RecordFieldList.AtLeftMargin=FALSE
SplitAndOr=FALSE
AndOrAfterExpression=FALSE
```

Fonte do Exemplo de Roles File: https://community.oracle.com/thread/899336?tstart=0

Fonte da configuração:
https://lalitkumarb.com/tag/oracle-plsql-developer-settings/

Comment: @pnet, deixei de mencionar alguns detalhes referente ao o que você precisa especificamente,  se não conseguir comente aqui, e então altero a resposta com mais detalhes.